# "insufficient storage" though nothing is installed

Tags: applications, google-play-store, insufficient-memory

I can't download any apps onto my android tablet. I have put it back to factory settings and it has nothing saved on it at all and is still telling me I have insufficient storage. I can't even install the cache cleaner.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! I've just added the `insufficient-memory` tag to your question. Please follow up to [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info): as that's a quite frequent question here, we've compiled some first-aid there. Check if that helps you, then come back here to answer your own question if solved or edit it and let us know what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: Hi and welcome! What make and model of tablet? How much storage space does it include? Have you "rooted" it?

Answer (score 0):

This a common problem faced by rooted phone users.
If you have any app that links your files to Sd like link2sd, luckypatcher...
and your phone doesn't support it. You'll have to revert all this apps setting to get the memory back. The actual problem is that you are linking to a directory which doesn't actually exist.